# Angular: setter input with sideffect

Tags: angular

I'm reading angular docs.It just spawned a doubt in my mind about the following sentence [REF](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#avoid-side-effects)

> "evaluation of a template expression should have no visible side
>   effects..."

If i understood correctly, it's because 
a "single detection cycle" executes the "templete expression": 
if that template expressions alters an info on which the rendered view depends, 
it won't show the change **within that detection cycle**...

My doubt is: **for the same reason, 
is it safe to say that**

> a component with input a setter must not allow the setter to have
>   visible side effects

**Example**
Can the following result in: *the "list" does not render correctly when passing an input to the component*

```
interface MyType{
    description: string
}

@Component({
    selector: 'my-cmp',
    template: `
        <div *ngFor="let item of _list">{{item.description}}</div>
    `
}),
export class MyComponentList{

    _list: MyType[];

    @Input() set list( items: MyType[] ){
        if(isListValid){
            this._list = items;
        }
        this._list = [];
    }

    isListValid( aList: MyType[] ): boolean{
        // logic
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "evaluation of a template expression should have no visible side
>   effects..."

It means, that is you use something in the template, the fact that you used it, should not have any side effects like perfomring an request, changing data model, modyfying dom etc, changing some properties.

The last case can be annoying and hard to debug as you can get `ValueChangedAfterCheckedException`  errors when - for example - you are incrementing some counter everytime you use some sort of getter method, that is also used in the template.

Now as for your statement:

> a component with input a setter must not allow the setter to have
>   visible side effects

that rly depends on the case - in general there will be no problem with that, as @Inputs are evaluated and bound before target component is initialized/has detection run on it, thus it can alter compontents state.

So in your case, everything will be fine, as setter will run before change detecion/rerender of component happens. Otherwise - it falls back to "no side effects" general rule.

If you take closer look, you will see that `onChanges` (thats called when @input/@output is involved) is the FIRST LIFECYCLE CALBACK of the angular component. (Its even before `onInit` callback). So that is the place to do modifications - and setters are invoked even before that.